# SQl to Excel keeps formatting to E+03

Tags: sql, excel

so I keep trying to export sql columns with values that have 8005E1 and it keeps showing up excel as '8005E+03'

is there a way i can prevent that? do i need to add a function to my sql query or something?

I tried editing the format to text but then it converts my string from '8005E1' to '8005' is which I don't want

any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the column as Text BEFORE you put the data in the column.

Comment: so my program converts the sql into an excelsheet, the excel is not opened beforehand if that makes sense

Comment: it does, you need to set the format of the cells in which you are putting the value BEFORE the value is placed.  If you are creating a csv from the output then you need to make it a .txt and import it instead of opening.  During the import phase you can dictate how the conversion takes place. Then you would need to save it as an xlsx not a txt or csv to maintain the format. If you just open it, then Excel will try to turn anything that looks like a number to a number.  There is no work around.